# How can I add a curve to a geometry using threejs?

Tags: three.js

I am creating a 3D plane using the pseudo code below.

```
  var point_records = [
    new THREE.Vector3(0,  0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(100,0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(100,50, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0,50, 0),
  ]

  let shape = new three.Shape(point_records); 

  let geometry = new three.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape, {
      depth: 1,
      bevelEnabled: false,
      steps: 1,
      bevelThickness: 0,
      bevelSize: 10,
      bevelSegments: 0,
      material: 0,
      extrudeMaterial: 1
    } );
    
  var mesh = new three.Mesh(geometry, materials);
```

This creates a 3d flat plane. I want to add a curve to this plane.

My initial idea is that I need to subdivide the plane into a lot of smaller triangles so I can manipulate their coordinates. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Specifically for a rectangular shape, you can use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()` with some segmentation on width and height.